Grouping sports data in a dataframe and aggregating it into a new table in R
Let's say I have a dataframe df like this:
       Home      Away HomeGoals AwayGoals HomePoints AwayPoints
1   Arsenal   Chelsea         3         1          3          0
2   Chelsea Liverpool         0         0          1          1
3 Liverpool   Arsenal         2         1          3          0
4   Chelsea   Arsenal         4         5          0          3
5 Liverpool   Chelsea         3         2          3          0
6   Arsenal Liverpool         2         2          1          1

I would like to produce a new dataframe FinalStandings showing team standings, sorted by Total Points, Goal Difference and Goals Scored, in descending order. So I would need to introduce new columns Team,   TotalPoints , GoalDiff , and GoalsScored. So for Arsenal, the corresponding row of  FinalStandings should look like this:
     Team TotalPoints GoalDiff GoalsScored
 Arsenal           7        2          11

I suppose I need to use the library(dplyr) (or maybe some other way) along with some sort of aggregating group_by() type functions, but I am struggling to implement it and get it to work. Please show how can one achieve the desired result efficiently?
Edit: note that each team appears in both "Home" and "Away" columns in df, so one cannot just simply group by Home or Awaycolumn.
One way I can think of is to do group_by on Home column and perform some summary operation,  then do the same onAway, then usecbind to combine together. But seems I need to do the whole operation several times. Is there a faster way?

That's not quite right though - for example, each team appears in both "Home" and "Away" column, as well as the points and thus GoalsScored  for each team should be GoalsScored + AwayGoals , right? @JonSpring

And similar for TotalPoints @JonSpring

Another solution which is kind of similar in the single steps to the one from @Jon Spring but uses a different selection strategy to achieve the same result.
Step 1 -  create intermediate helper columns GoalDiff. The columns in df are alternating for Home and Away so we keep this format for the new columns.
df_temp <- df %>%
  mutate(HomeGoalDiff = HomeGoals - AwayGoals,
         AwayGoalDiff = - HomeGoalDiff)

Step 2 - omit the Home and Away prefixes as we know they are alternating and we select the columns by index.
colnames(df_temp) <- rep(c("Team","Goal","Points","Diff"), each=2)

Step 3 - Select the Home and Away columns to create another dataframe that can be used to aggregate the metrics per Team.
FinalStandings <- bind_rows(
    df_temp %>% select(seq(1,7,2)), # home cols 1,3,5,7
    df_temp %>% select(seq(2,8,2))  # away cols 2,4,6,8
  ) %>%
  group_by(Team) %>%
  summarise(TotalPoints = sum(Points),
            GoalDiff = sum(Diff),
            GoalsScored = sum(Goal)) %>%
  arrange(desc(TotalPoints), desc(GoalDiff), desc(GoalsScored))

Step 4 - print the result
FinalStandings

#  Team      TotalPoints GoalDiff GoalsScored
#   <chr>           <dbl>    <dbl>       <dbl>
# 1 Liverpool           8        2           7
# 2 Arsenal             7        2          11
# 3 Chelsea             1       -4           7



Here's an approach using pivoting. First I add columns for goals scored by the opponent, since we want that later:
df2 <- df |> mutate(HomeGoalsOpp = AwayGoals, AwayGoalsOpp = HomeGoals)

Then I map how to treat each column, where we want to split each one after Home/Away, and for the columns that are just Home/Away, put those values in a Team column.
spec <- data.frame(.name = names(df2)) |>
  separate_wider_regex('.name', c(location = "Home|Away", .value = ".*"), 
                       cols_remove = FALSE) |>
  mutate(across(.value, ~if_else(.x =="", "Team", .x)))

Now we use that mapping to pivot, and then sum by team:
df2 |>
  pivot_longer_spec(spec) |>
  summarize(TotalPoints = sum(Points),
            GoalDiff = sum(Goals) - sum(GoalsOpp),
            GoalsScored = sum(Goals), .by = Team)

Result
# A tibble: 3 × 4
  Team      TotalPoints GoalDiff GoalsScored
  <chr>           <int>    <int>       <int>
1 Arsenal             7        2          11
2 Chelsea             1       -4           7
3 Liverpool           8        2           7


Maybe there's a more efficient way but this seems to work.
Splitting the problem into 3 parts, first calculating the "Home" and "Away" stats, respectively, then adding GoalDiff, each combined by left_joins.
EDIT, added the "Away" GoalDiff stats
library(dplyr)

left_join(df[,grep("Home", colnames(df))] %>% 
            summarize(across(everything(), ~ sum(.x)), .by = Home), 
          df[,grep("Away", colnames(df))] %>% 
            summarize(across(everything(), ~ sum(.x)), .by = Away), 
    join_by("Home" == "Away")) %>%
  left_join(
    left_join(
          df %>% 
            summarize(x = sum(HomeGoals - AwayGoals), .by = Home), 
          df %>%
            summarize(y = sum(AwayGoals - HomeGoals), .by = Away), 
          join_by("Home" == "Away")) %>%
          reframe(GoalDiff = rowSums(across(x:y)), .by = Home), 
    join_by(Home)) %>%
  rename(Team = Home) %>% 
  reframe(TotalPoints = HomePoints + AwayPoints, 
          GoalDiff, 
          GoalsScored = HomeGoals + AwayGoals, .by = Team)

output
       Team TotalPoints GoalDiff GoalsScored
1   Arsenal           7        2          11
2   Chelsea           1       -4           7
3 Liverpool           8        2           7

Data
df <- structure(list(Home = c("Arsenal", "Chelsea", "Liverpool", "Chelsea", 
"Liverpool", "Arsenal"), Away = c("Chelsea", "Liverpool", "Arsenal", 
"Arsenal", "Chelsea", "Liverpool"), HomeGoals = c(3L, 0L, 2L, 
4L, 3L, 2L), AwayGoals = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 2L), HomePoints = c(3L, 
1L, 3L, 0L, 3L, 1L), AwayPoints = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 1L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))


@JonSpring You're right. I missed the Away part for GoalDiff, gonna edit!
